# will and would differences

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

> 1). Without my coach it **wouldn't** be possible.

> 2). Without my coach it **will not** be possible.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences???

I Know that "would" is used in hypothetical sentences, what might be the unstated hypothetical condition in the first sentence.

Comment: It's not unstated.  The hypothetical condition is the absence of the coach.  In the first, the most likely interpretations are that it will be possible or it is possible, because the coach will be or has been present.  In the second, one likely interpretation is that it will not be possible if the coach doesn't arrive.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the first is hypothetical (grammarians say *irrealis* or *counter-factual*).

> Without my coach it wouldn't be possible => If I didn't have my coach it wouldn't be possible, but I do have it.

The second is an unknown possibility, but is not counter-factual, or *irrealis*:

> Without my coach it won't (will not) be possible => If I don't have my coach at the relevant time, it will not be possible (and I don't know if I will have my coach then or not).